# Как сделать такой свайп?

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно на чистом js перелистывать блоки.

[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/dtCqRv0)

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживаешь ontouchstart и записываешь координаты прикосновения, а потом в слушателе ивента ontouchmove в зависимости от перемещения прикосновения решаешь перелистывать блок или нет.